# Unable to launch URL (endpoint) from docker container image

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-container

I am unable to launch the URL of Web API from the docker containerized image.
I have entirely no idea what's the reason behind that. I have confirmed that from locally that endpoint is invokable but the docker containerized image is not able to show the running server while it is being accessed from outside.

**Following is the Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS debug
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SOME.dll"]
```

**Following is docker-compose.yml file.**

```
    version: '3.9'

services:
  db:  
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: app_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: machinestatusdb
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=root@root.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    ports: 
      - '5055:80'

  machinestatusapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8088:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: machinestatus-service
    environment:
      - ConnectionString_DefaultConnection=User ID=root;Password=root;Server=app_db;Port=5432;Database=machinestatusdb;IntegratedSecurity=true;Pooling=true;
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
```

While I could see the containers in my Visual Studio Code as :

[image]

Moreover, the following is the structure of my project.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MachineStatusController : ControllerBase
{    
    private readonly ILogger<MachineStatusController> _logger;
    private readonly IMachineStatusEventRepository _machineStatusRepo;

    public MachineStatusController(ILogger<MachineStatusController> logger, 
                                   IMachineStatusEventRepository machineStatusRepo)
    {
        _machineStatusRepo = machineStatusRepo;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "events")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)]

    public async Task<ActionResult<MachineStatus>> GetAllEvents()
    {       
        return Unauthorized();
    }    
}
```

The above controller returns perfectly correct results when run locally. However, from the docker container image, it returns `NotFound`. I am completely using the same URL to access what I generated from Dockerfile (i.e. `localhost:8088/api/machinestatus`). But it's not working.
Can any body help me in this regards?